# Scala class from atmosphere-play not found in Java application

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, atmosphere

I"m trying to add Atmosphere to a Play! Java project created by a colleague.  I'm using Play 2.5.4

As a first step, I"m just trying to add the Chat example.  I've copied everything verbatim from what passes for documentation from atmosphere-play.

My build.sbt contains the following dependencies (I also had atmosphere-runtime in, but that doesn't seem to be required and may, in fact, conflict with atmosphere-play)

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 // javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
 ... unrelated stuff ...
  "org.atmosphere.client" % "javascript" % "2.3.2",
   "org.atmosphere" % "atmosphere-play" % "2.3.0"
)
```

In Global.java (yeah, I know, but the Play docs say you need it to support onRouteRequest):

```
package controllers;

import org.atmosphere.play.AtmosphereCoordinator;
import play.Application;
import play.GlobalSettings;
import play.api.mvc.Handler;
import play.mvc.Http.RequestHeader;
import org.atmosphere.play.Router;
import controllers.Chat;

import static org.atmosphere.play.AtmosphereCoordinator.*;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    @Override
    public void onStart(Application application) {
        instance().discover(Chat.class).ready();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(Application application) {
        instance().shutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public Handler onRouteRequest(RequestHeader request) {
        return Router.dispatch(request);
    }

}
```

WHen I compile:

```
[coaster-ui] $ compile
[info] Updating {file:/stuff/web/react/}root...
[info] Resolving net.contentobjects.jnotify#jnotify;0.94-play-1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 8 Scala sources and 9 Java sources to /stuff/web/react/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /stuff/web/react/app/controllers/Global.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
[error] import org.atmosphere.play.Router;
[error]                           ^
[error]   symbol:   class Router
[error]   location: package org.atmosphere.play
[error] 1 error
[error] (compile:compile) javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] Total time: 6 s, completed Jul 13, 2016 11:22:07 AM
[coaster-ui] $
```

I feel like I must be missing something really basic, but can't seem to figure out what it is.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: betseyb - there is no `Router` in Atmosphere 2.3.0 - check the source here - https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-play/tree/play-project-2.3.0/module
Are you sure you are looking at the up-to-date docs for Atmosphere?

Comment: I couldn't find any real docs for atmosphere-play.  That was part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Scala `org.atmosphere.play.Router` was replaced by [AtmosphereHttpRequestHandler.scala](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-play/blob/play-project-2.2.0/module/src/main/scala/org/atmosphere/play/AtmosphereHttpRequestHandler.scala) in 2.2.0.

You could try downgrading Atmosphere to 2.1.0 to see if it compiles with your existing code. The chat sample uses the [2.1.0-SNAPSHOT](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-samples/blob/master/play-samples/chat/build.sbt) which is probably where the confusion comes from if your existing source is based off of that.

Comment: I wanted to use the most recent version of atmosphere-play, as I needed it to work with Play 2.5.  I couldn't find anything in the documentation that explained the replacement, which would have helped!  I have it working now, thankfully.